# 'The executable 'bsdtar' Vagrant is trying to run was not found in the PATH variable' in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I am having the following error message on `vagrant up`

```
The executable 'bsdtar' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libarchive-tools
```

but got the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libarchive-tools
```

Answer (score 5):

I just setup a vagrant box with archlinux on ubuntu 20.04 and also got the same error. I was able to fix my issue by running

```
sudo apt install libarchive-tools
```

Maybe you need to run

```
sudo apt update
```

to update your apt database